# TypeError this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: django

I seem to be having a TypeError problem on my program using Django.

Views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Anteproyecto
from .forms import formulario_anteproyecto
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class CrearAnteproyecto(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Anteproyecto
    form_class = formulario_anteproyecto
    template_name = "crear_anteproyectos.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('crear_anteproyecto')
    success_message = "El anteproyecto ha sido creado"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
```

Forms. py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Anteproyecto

class formulario_anteproyecto:
    class Meta:
        model = Anteproyecto
        fields = ['titulo', 'resumen','estado','palabras_claves']
```

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from Actividades.models import Actividades

ESTADOS = (('Activo', 'Activo'), ('Inactivo', 'Inactivo'))

class Anteproyecto(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Título')
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=8, verbose_name="Estado", choices=ESTADOS, default='Activo')
    resumen = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Resumen")
    claves = TaggableManager(verbose_name = "Palabras claves")
    actividad = models.ForeignKey(Actividades, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta :
        verbose_name = 'Anteproyecto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Anteproyectos'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Importing the app "Actividades" to be used as a reference in models. Using as well Django-taggit to use a field that can work as tags, still not implemented due to TypeError. Html is a bootstrap template which prints the form as a paragraph. There are other creates in different views that use the same coding as this however this one is giving me the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `formulario_anteproyecto` does not inherit from anything. It needs to inherit from `forms.ModelForm`.

Comment: I knew I would be missing something small. Thank you.